# QTableWidget Selection of rows is too slow

Tags: qt

I need to programmatically select rows in QTableWidget. I found 3 ways to do it but all of them are very slow. The same time a can instantly select thousands or rows by CTRL+A or SHIFT+mouse click.

My code is:

```
// tw is QTableWidget
tw->blockSignals(true); // Disable all signals for testing
// Need to select multiple rows without resetting selection
tw->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::MultiSelection);

for(int i = 0; i < tw->rowCount(); i++)
{
    if(conditionForSelection)
    {
        // Next line is very slow. It takes minutes to select
        // thousands of rows
        //tw->selectRow(i);

        // Very slow too
        // tw->item(i, 0)->setSelected(true);

        // This line is faster but it still takes tens of seconds
        tw->setCurrentIndex(tw->model()->index(i, 0));
    }
}

// return normal selection behavior and signals
tw->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::ExtendedSelection);
tw->blockSignals(false);
```

Iteration itself is nearly instant too. Only selection in problematic. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you try the selection without `conditionForSelection`  and compare result ... just select all rows, may be the problem is not in selection

Comment: If I comment selection string, iteration and condition are nearly instant.

Comment: Problem is probably in that selection string, you certainly need to check why, in the code above its not shown

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, I recommend to store all indexes that need to be chosen in collection and(also you can do the same for the deselected ones) use

```
self.selectionModel().select(QItemSelection(selected_indexes[0],selected_indexes[-1]),QItemSelectionModel.Select)
```

Example is written in the PyQt, i believe it wouldnt be a problem to change it to c++.

Comment: Yes this is the way, create indexes and pass directly to `selectionModel().select()`. I can select thousands of rows instantaneously and without creating 'blocks' of selection, too.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to select just a subset or all of them?

For all, there is `QTableWidget::selectAll()`

If just a subset, have you tried doing via the selection model?

`tw->selectionModel()->select(tw->item(i,0));`

Comment: Select function is very slow when I select one item by one or pass to it QItemSelection with a lot of values. The only fast method to programmatically select a lot of rows is to form a few ranges of rows (usually I have to select rows which follow each other) and select them by QItemSelection->select.